# Struts 2 JSON interceptor for Custom Maps

Tags: java, regex, json, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

I have following POJO's

```
public class Category {
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private String description;

    //many more attributes below
}

public class User {
        private Integer id;
        private String name;
        private String address;

           //many more attributes below
    }

public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {

       //list of objects
    List<Category> categories;

       //Complex Map
    private Map<Category, List<User>> categorizedUsers;

       //getters and setters

    @Override
    public String execute() {

        //populate "categories" and "categorizedUsers" with some business logic
        return SUCCESS;  
}
}
```

I make an AJAX call for this action and expect the data (i.e. "categories" and "categorizedUsers") in JSON format. Struts2 provides us with JSON interceptor where I can specifically filter the parameters to be serailized.

Following is configuration in struts xml file

```
<action name="mywidget" class="com.struts.action.MyAction">
     <result type="json">
        <param name="includeProperties">
           ^categories\[\d+\]\.id, 
           ^categories\[\d+\]\.title,
        </param>
    </result>
</action>
```

Both the POJOs contain a lot of attributes, but with `"includeproperties"`, I was able to filter out id and title for each `Category` in the list.

However for the map key as well as value, I'm unable to apply any such regex pattern to filter out desired attributes. (Lets say for the map key `Category`, I need `id` and `title`, whereas for each Value `User`, I need to filter out `id`, `name` only). Please suggest appropriate regex pattern to be applied on the  `Map<Category, List<User>>`.